# How can I avoid the conversion dialog when opening a PDF through Word Interop?

Tags: c#, pdf, office-interop

I'm trying to open PDF and save it as a html file using C#.

the main code is as following:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
Document doc = word.Documents.Open((string)wordfilename,
MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

while when the wordfilename is a pdf file, there will be a popped-up window to ask me to choose for input file type as "PDF".

Is there any way to avoid the popped-up window by setting the Format when using Open API ?

I found some clues in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835182.aspx
but don't know how to  "**apply the OpenFormat property to aFileConverter object to determine the value to use with this argument**."

Comment: You aren't using an Office dll, you are trying to start Word to read a PDF. Why don't you use the Acrobat SDK instead?